# Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, jaas, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to connect to Kafka from spark structured streaming.

This works:

```sh
spark-shell --master local[1] \
       --files /mypath/jaas_mh.conf \
       --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 \
       --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas_mh.conf" \
       --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas_mh.conf" \
       --num-executors 1  --executor-cores 1
```

However, when I try to do the same programmatically ..

```scala
object SparkHelper {
  def getAndConfigureSparkSession() = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Structured Streaming from Message Hub to Cassandra")
      .setMaster("local[1]")
      .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas_mh.conf")
      .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas_mh.conf")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    getSparkSession()
  }

  def getSparkSession() : SparkSession = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.addFile("/mypath/jaas_mh.conf")

    return spark
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
 Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. 
    System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in the conf you should provide full path or relative path for the .conf file.
Also, when you create SparkConf I see that you are not applying it to the current SparkSession.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Driver extends App {

  val confPath: String = "/Users/arcizon/IdeaProjects/spark/src/main/resources/jaas_mh.conf"

  def getAndConfigureSparkSession(): SparkSession = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Structured Streaming from Message Hub to Cassandra")
      .setMaster("local[1]")
      .set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", s"-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$confPath")
      .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", s"-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$confPath")

    getSparkSession(conf)
  }

  def getSparkSession(conf: SparkConf): SparkSession = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.addFile(confPath)

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    spark
  }

  val sparkSession: SparkSession = getAndConfigureSparkSession()

  println(sparkSession.conf.get("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions"))
  println(sparkSession.conf.get("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions"))

  sparkSession.stop()
}
```

Comment: I also had to set as a system property because I was running in client mode: `System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas_mh.conf")`